# Callable Future, How can I shutdown and restart ServerSocket Callable threads from an executing class that hands off successful socket connections?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, oop, design-patterns

I would like to execute server threads that return sockets when successful incoming socket connections are made, and are easily shut down... simply and cleanly.

---

ServerSocketThread.java :

Creates a ServerSocket listening on a port

returns Socket An incoming client connection

```
public class ServerSocketThread implements Callable<Socket> {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Integer listeningPort;

    public SocketListener(Integer listeningPort) {
        this.listeningPort = listeningPort;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket call() throws Exception {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(listeningPort);
        return serverSocket.accept();
    }

    public interrupt() throws IOException {
        serverSocket.close();
    }

}
```

---

However, my current implementation of what executes these threads is:

ServerSocketExecutor.java :

Creates ServerSocketListener threads

Observes incoming Sockets from ServerSocketListener threads

Produces incoming Sockets to its Mediator

```
public class ServerSocketExecutor extends Producer<Socket> implements Observer {

    List<Integer> listeningPorts = Collections.emptyList();

    public ServerSocketExecutor(List<Integer> listeningPorts) {
        this.listeningPorts = listeningPorts;
    }

    public Void call() throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(listeningPorts.size());
        List<ServerSocketListener> socketListeners = new ArrayList<ServerSocketListener>();

        // Instantiate new ServerSocketListener for each listeningPort
        for (Integer port : listeningPorts) {
            socketListeners.add(new ServerSocketListener(this).listenOnPort(port));
        }

        try {
            executor.invokeAll(socketListeners);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        return null;
    }

    public synchronized void update(Observable o, Object socket) {
        produce((Socket) socket); // Produces to Mediator<Socket>
    }
}
```

---

And my ServerSocketListener.java is:

ServerSocketListener.java:

Listens for an incoming connection on a given port

Notifies an observer of a Socket connection

Continues listening for incoming connections

```
public class ServerSocketListener extends Observable implements Callable<Void> {

    ServerSocket server;
    private Integer listeningPort;
    Boolean runnable = true;

    public ServerSocketListener(Observer o) {
        addObserver(o);
    }

    public ServerSocketListener listenOnPort(Integer listeningPort) {
        this.listeningPort = listeningPort;
        return this;
    }

    public Void call() throws Exception {
        server = new ServerSocket(listeningPort, 10);

        while (runnable) {
            Socket socket = server.accept();

            setChanged();
            notifyObservers(socket);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void interrupt() throws IOException {
        runnable = false;
        server.close();
    }
}
```

---

I'm stuck on some of the fundamental behaviors this pair of threads should have.

I'm not certain what a List<Future<Void>> can provide me with in my ServerSocketExecutor. Can Future<Void> address some of my concerns with thread termination?

How do I cleanly terminate these threads? ServerSocketListener ignores executor.shutdown() and future.get() blocks. Terminating the ServerSocketThread class is easy, terminating something that's blocking seems really difficult.

I've seen people say to use:

```
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
```

but I'm not sure how to invoke it, if it will negatively affect these threads, or what exceptions I should need to catch and where.

Last, but not least, how can I re-run a ServerSocketThread after it returns a future? ServerSocketExecutor will need to regenerate ServerSocket threads after they're shut down. The alternative is to run them in a loop... but that leads to my current implementation which brings me back to square one.

I know this is a lot, but all I can really do right now is stare at this code like a goldfish and I need a kick in the rear.

Comment: I think you're trying to be a bit too clever here. If I saw code like this, I'd tell the person to either refactor it, or explain with valid reasons why he does something like this. If you intend to listen on a single port for multiple connections, it doesn't make sense to recreate Callables just for that. What is the actual problem you think your design solves?

Comment: @Kayaman Explain with valid reasons why observers and mediators decouple processes from one another? Because they do.

The actual problems this design solves are blocking and polling threads, obviously. Socket connections are produced to a mediator the moment they become available, and consumers are notified to pull from the shared queue.

It's a very simple solution to a classic producer/consumer problem. It isn't just for Sockets, it's for any thread that relies on output from some other autonomous and decoupled thread (which there are a lot of in my own and many other applications).

Comment: @Kayaman These are also multiple ports and multiple connections. I agree a single port doesn't require an executor but this does (and ServerSocketChannels are even worse). This is basically a thread-safe, type-safe list of future.get()s that don't block while waiting for a result.

If you want to learn more about this problem watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-rKLSdPEMs) to see how they solved it.

All I care about is how to shut these threads down cleanly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it when I have the time. As well as take another look at this question.